# cMake Error and failed to invoke

Tags: ros, geometry-msgs, rasbperrypi

[image: Rosanswers logo]

while i was doing rosmake i got errors.
After running "rosmake roomba_500driver_meiji " i got errors below.

```
    mkdir -p bin
  cd build && cmake -Wdev -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=/opt/ros/indigo/share/ros/core/rosbuild/rostoolchain.cmake  ..
  [rosbuild] Building package roomba_500driver_meiji
  Failed to invoke /opt/ros/indigo/bin/rospack deps-manifests roomba_500driver_meiji
  [rospack] Error: package 'roomba_500driver_meiji' depends on non-existent package 'geometry_msgs' and rosdep claims that it is not a system dependency. Check the ROS_PACKAGE_PATH or try calling 'rosdep update'
  
  
  CMake Error at /opt/ros/indigo/share/ros/core/rosbuild/public.cmake:129 (message):
    
  
    Failed to invoke rospack to get compile flags for package
    'roomba_500driver_meiji'.  Look above for errors from rospack itself.
    Aborting.  Please fix the broken dependency!
  
  Call Stack (most recent call first):
    /opt/ros/indigo/share/ros/core/rosbuild/public.cmake:207 (rosbuild_invoke_rospack)
    CMakeLists.txt:12 (rosbuild_init)
  
  
  -- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
  See also "/home/pi/ros_catkin_ws/src/roomba_robot_meiji/roomba_500driver_meiji/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
  /home/pi/ros_catkin_ws/src/ros/mk/cmake.mk:7: recipe for target 'all' failed
```

here is ROS_PACKAGE_PATH

```
/home/pi/ros_catkin_ws/src:/home/pi/ros_catkin_ws/src/ros_comm/rosbag:/opt/ros/indigo/share:/opt/ros/indigo/stacks
```

i also get this error by running rosdep keys geometry_msgs

```
    ERROR: Rosdep cannot find all required resources to answer your query
Missing resource geometry_msgs
ROS path [0]=/opt/ros/indigo/share/ros
ROS path [1]=/home/pi/ros_catkin_ws/src
ROS path [2]=/home/pi/ros_catkin_ws/src/ros_comm/rosbag
ROS path [3]=/opt/ros/indigo/share
ROS path [4]=/opt/ros/indigo/stacks
```

i thought these errors were coused by lack of ROS path but im not sure.
by the way the folder "geometry_msgs" is located at `/home/pi/ros_catkin_ws/src/genmsg/test/files/geometry_msgs/msg`

im using Raspberry pi, os is Jessie and i installed indigo.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/221506/cmake-error-and-failed-to-invoke/) by [Pato](https://answers.ros.org/users/24802/pato/) on ROS Answers with karma: 5 on 2015-11-25

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Chrissi](https://answers.ros.org/users/15386/chrissi/) on 2015-11-26**:
You use `rosbuild` in Indigo? Is that even supported any more? Why not `catkin_make`?

**Comment by [Fredylucas](https://answers.ros.org/users/25070/fredylucas/) on 2015-11-26**:
I'm not sure, but I understand rosmake is a tool for compiling a single package, not all the packages in the workspace as when using catkin_make, and it also works in ROS Indigo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In the error message, it says geometry_msgs package is missing, are you sure you have this package? it says this missing package is necessary for compiling the roomba_500driver_meiji package.

---

Originally posted by [Fredylucas](https://answers.ros.org/users/25070/fredylucas/) with karma: 123 on 2015-11-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Pato](https://answers.ros.org/users/24802/pato/) on 2015-12-04**:
Thank you for answereing.
I'm sure that there is the roomba_500driver_meiji package.
but I don't know what to do, so i will try to reinstall ROS.